# Java anonymous classes usage

Tags: java, inner-classes, anonymous-class

```
package wrap;

public class Anonymous {

    public Circle getCircle(int radius){

        return new Circle(radius){
            private int rad;
            public double area() { 
                return 3.14*rad*rad;
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Anonymous p = new Anonymous(); 
        Circle w = p.getCircle(10); 
        System.out.println(w.area()); 
    }
 }
    class Circle { 
        private int rad; 
        public Circle(int radius) {
            rad = radius; 
        } 
        public double area() { 
            return rad*rad; 
        }
    }
```

I have created anonymous inner class of Circle inside getcircle method.But invoking getcircle method is not displaying "I am inside".Why is it so?? Anonymous class should override the outer Circle class.

Comment: Why did you expect it to print `"I am inside"`? You don't have a constructor, but a method with the name `Circle` in the anonymous class.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
public void Circle(int radius) {
```

is a method declaration with a return type `void`, not a constructor.

[The Java language specification states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5.1)

> **An anonymous class cannot have an explicitly declared constructor.**
>   Instead, a Java compiler must automatically provide an anonymous
>   constructor for the anonymous class.

Since you never call the `Circle(int)` method declared above, the `String` `"I am inside"` is never printed.

Comment: I am getting 0.0 as output.I was expecting 314 as output

Comment: @Pavan You've declared a field called `rad` in your anonymous class that is hiding the field of the same name in the super class `Circle`. When you refer to it in the overriden `area` method, you are referring to the anonymous class' field, which is initialized to `0` by default.